# Code for Numericupdownextender event handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, numericupdown, extender

i want to change image of an image control based on the value of textbox by clicking on the ajax numericupdownextender control.Please provide solution in c# and also tell me how we can write custom code for this.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried already? We'd like to help you with a specific problem. We're not really the kind of site that writes code for you, we're the kind that helps you fix problems.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you'll want to use the currentChanged event of the NumericUpDownExtender. This fires an event client side (in javascript - not C#).

"The NumericUpDown extender has only one event, currentChanged. This event is fired whenever the value of the extended textbox is changed through the up/down buttons or when the user types a new value in that textbox. In case of typing, the event fires whenever the focus leaves the textbox."

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
    $find('<%= NumericUpDownExtenderID.ClientID %>').add_currentChanged(methodtocall);
}

function methodtocall(sender, e) {
    alert(String.format('change event fired. Value: {0}', e));
}
```

If this doesn't solve your problem then you need to be clearer in your question.